# Как во vue значение массива string преобразовать в ingeter

Tags: vue.js

У меня массив  total. В нем данные в типе string [ "5", "3", "5" ].Подскажите как их всех преобразовать в integer => [5, 3, 5]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да просто через `map` преобразовать:

```js
const array = ['1', '2', '3']
console.log(array.map( (el) => Number(el) ))
```